# Use Web Worker and D3.js to asynchronously generate graphs?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, web-worker

I'm currently working a problem that requires my web application to generate a chart that represents approximately 50k to 60k points of data. It loads fairly quickly (~6 seconds), but what I'm wondering if it is possible to use D3.js to generate the graph in a Web Worker and then pass the SVG back to be loaded into the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web Workers have no DOM access, so all you could do on that side would be to build something that could be used for quickly creating the DOM. The worker(s) could e.g process the datasets and do all the heavy computations, then pass the result back as a set of arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this would be the answer.

Comment: @meetamit that could be an option I guess, generate the DOM on the server with phantomJS and then pass it to the client? but that's not using Web Workers though, which was the question.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/43d38773623b52209d2667287a1ae626fb95b0d9

A recent commit by Jason Davies. Mike Bostock says that in future the DOM dependent code will be separated from d3.core and that way you can make a custom d3 build that works with web-workers API.

I had the same problem where I have a force directed graph with a large number of nodes. It feels very sluggish. I want to improve the performance in some way. I think the last thread with phantomJS on a node server is a good idea, but the network latency involved in the approach will ruin the smooth force-directed feeling.

Comment: so where do you find the stripped D3 without dom dependencies ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to calculate the chords and groups of a chord layout using a web worker by doing the following:

1. create a custom build of d3 that doesn't have a dependecy on the document object or the DOM (see: https://github.com/mbostock/smash/wiki)
2. create a web worker file and use `importScripts` to load the custom d3 build
3. activate your worker in your rendering code. I used a promise to encapsulate the communication with the worker:

   ```
   calculateChords = (padding, matrix) ->
           deferred = $.Deferred()

           worker = new Worker("worker.js")

           worker.onmessage = (e) ->
               deferred.resolve(e.data.groups, e.data.chords);

           worker.postMessage {
               matrix: matrix
           }

           deferred.promise()
   ```

   later, in the rendering function:

   ```
   calculateChords(matrix).then (groups, chords) ->
       ...
   ```

Comment: You can actually run standard d3 in a web worker if you leave the right (fake) objects lying arround to placate d3 as its booting up. The main problem though (in using d3 with web workers) is the serialisation overheads in send and receive message. I would be very interested to know if anyone has come up with a nice method for using transferable objects to obviate the serialisation though.